# use a partial view in a $route template angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

Hi i am trying to use a partial view in my angular `$route` template but it is not working property and the $http.get request in the controller is being called 7 times. I am returning the partial view from my MVC controller.. can you use a partial view with the angular $route template?.. i have seen some answers using just the `View()` but nothing with PartialViews any ideas?

Route:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/a-7/", {
           templateUrl: window.location.origin + '/View/GetDetails'
          })
      });
</script>
```

MVC Controller it calls

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetDetails()
{
   return PartialView("~/Views/Test/_TestDetails.cshtml");
}
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
app.controller("Details", function ($routeParams, $scope, $http, $route) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.Id= $routeParams.id;
    $http.get("/View/GetDetailsData", { params: { id: $scope.Id} })
    .then(function(response){
       $scope.Test = response.data;
       $("#myModal").modal()
    })
});
```

Partial view

```
<div data-ng-controller="Details as $ctrl" class="Details">
       <p>{{ Test }}
</div>
```

Comment: this should work, but I wouldn't recommend having your view and your data both be `GetDetails` on the server;  if your `$routeParams.id` is null, then your `$http.get` would be calling `GetDetails` with no parameters, which means it will be fetching your partial view, which is a problem.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake it is not pointing to the same controller, at the moment it works but it calls the $http.get 7 times any ideas? or if my approach is wrong?

Comment: what does `$('#myModal").modal()` do?  that's not angular, it's jquery, and not angular aware;  if that modal is affecting the angular view in some way, it could be continually re-initializing the controller.  Otherwise, there isn't anything in this code that would cause that condition....

Comment: modal is just a jquery function if i remove that same thing happens.. its the $http.get on the controller which just keeps getting called 7 times before it goes into the .then clause? even if i return a empty partial view the same thing happens? can you 100% use a partial view on the template? i have only seen view examples?